# Can I use Eclipse templates to insert methods and also call them?

Tags: eclipse

I'm doing some competitions on a website called *topcoder.com* where the objective is to solve algorithmic problems. I'm using **Eclipse** for this purpose, and I code in **Java**, it would be help me to have some predefined templates or macros that I can use for common coding tasks. For example I would like to write methods to be able to find the max value in and int[] array, or the longest sequence in an int[] array, and so on (there should be quite many of these). Note I can't write these methods as libraries because as part of the competition I need to submit everything in one file.

Therefore ideally, I would like to have some shortcut available to generate code both as a method and as a calling statement at once. Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: Well... you can have classes inside of classes in Java. Its not best form but does meet that requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can - I think that's a nifty way to auto-insert boilerplate or helper code.  To the point of commenters, you probably want to group the code as a helper class, but the general idea sounds good to me:

[image: Editing Java editor template on eclipse Kepler]

You can see it listed in your available templates:

[image]

Then as you code your solution, you can Control+Space, type the first few characters of the name you gave your template, and you can preview it:

[image]

And then you can insert it.  Be sure if you use a class structure to position it as an inner class:

[image]

Lastly - if you want to have a template inserts a call to method from a template, I think you would just use two templates.  One like shown above (to print the helper code) and another that might look like this, which calls a util method and drops the cursor after it (or between the parentheses if you'd like, etc):

```
MyUtils.myUtilMethod1();${cursor}
```